# Compare values in column B of sheet 1 to column B of sheet 2; append unmatched values in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to help a colleague with an excel report. He is not very good with computers and is making errors in copying all the relevant data from one sheet to another. He's working with a dataset that looks like this:

]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHUpt.png (not allowed to upload images directly yet because i created a new account)

These are pending shipping values and everyday a report is generated with all the orders and the pending ones need to be copied into another sheet and then their status is updated in that excel sheet.

What I need is a solution that when I paste my report into sheet one, I can run a VBA code and compare all the values in column B of sheet one to all the values in column B of sheet two. Then, whatever is not present in column B of sheet two can be highlighted in sheet one or pasted into sheet three/ appended into sheet two. In this way, they operator does not have to do the lookup by himself.

If there is any other solution than VBA that could help, feel free to suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Sub CompareData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo 0

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change Sheet Name
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Change Sheet Name

ws1.Copy after:=ws2
Set ws3 = wb.ActiveSheet

Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim Rng As Range

With ws3
    LastRow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E1").Value = "Vlookup"
    .Range("E2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B2," & ws2.Name & "!B:B,1,0)"
    .Range("E2").Copy .Range("E3:E" & LastRow1)
    .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter FIELD:=5, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    Set Rng = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0)
    Set Rng = Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, 4)
End With

Dim LastRow2 As Long
LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Rng.Copy ws2.Range("A" & LastRow2 + 1 & ":D" & LastRow2 + 1)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws3.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ws2.Activate
Exit Sub
0:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

> Don't forget to change your sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks (comparing data in different worksheets), I usually use Excel built-in `IF` funcion. Example: `=IF([Workbook_1]Sheet_1!B1=[Workbook_2]Sheet_2!B1,".",FALSE)`. Then, just fill down the formula (dragging down).

**Note:** `.` is used for easiness of distinguishing `FALSE` values.